# Error message: "detected as a localLooping app."

Tags: android, admob

I have started seeing the following error message appearing occasionally in the logcat for an app I am developing:

> E/MbmAppStatsInternal(568): App appName=theAppName, is detected as a localLooping app.

Further digging highlights that it is coming from the Google AdMob code.

Any ideas ?

There is no apparent impact on the functioning of the app or the ads.

Thanks.